# Jackson XmlMapper: deserialize true/false as boolean values

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson2, jackson-dataformat-xml

I would like to convert xml structure into json by using Jackson library

input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmldata>
  <groups>
    <fields>
      <disabled>true</disabled>
    </fields>
  </groups>
</xmldata>
```

output json should be:

```
{
  "xmldata": {
    "groups": {
      "fields": { 
        "disabled": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but instead of **"disabled": true** (boolean) I get **"disabled": "true"** (string)

do I need to add some configuration or is it not possible out-of-the-box?

I'm using this mapper config:

```
JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();
module.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
XmlFactory xmlFactory = new XmlFactory(new WstxInputFactory(), new WstxOutputFactory());
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(xmlFactory, module);
xmlMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
xmlMapper.configure(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, true);
```

**PS: no POJOs involved (and I would like to keep it that way)**

Thx in advance

regards

Comment: I don't know the way how to do it without POJO class, because the `true` or `false` can be the text String. So, if you want boolean object, you need the POJO class, and specify boolean object there.